# C - get list of opened handlers - duplicate entries

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I have this code to retrieve list of opened handlers (mostly FILE)

```
int flags;
int fd;
char buf[MAXPATHLEN+1] ;
int n = 1 ;

for (fd = 0; fd < (int) FD_SETSIZE; fd++)
{
    errno = 0;
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
    if (flags == -1 && errno)
    {
        if (errno != EBADF)
        {
            return;
         }
     }

     fcntl(fd , F_GETPATH, buf ) ;
     printf( "File Descriptor %d number %d in use for: %s",fd,n , buf ) ;
    ++n ;
}
```

However, when i call single `fopen` and run this, it prints the same file multiple times (from `n` to `FD_SETSIZE`, where `n` is some offset id... first 0 .. `n` are some system handlers like dev/nul etc.).

Comment: `fopen` is not really a system call. Have you tried with `open` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error check after `fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0)` is a bit suspect. Assuming your intent is to bail after you hit the first bad `fd`, then the check should be `errno == EBADF`.

Also, I suggest checking result of your second `fcntl` before `printf`